# How to configure PhpMyAdmin on NGINX (Windows)

Tags: c#, php, windows, nginx, phpmyadmin

Today I started making a server with NGINX, I managed to set up PHP and MySQL, everything is going very well.
However, I need the NGINX open PhpMyAdmin (prior to being in the directory root [Example: C:\Server\WWW - ROOT / C:\Server\ - where will PhpMyAdmin])

I'm trying everything (noting that use Windows 7 Ultimate x64)
Can anyone help me?

My nginx.conf (complete)

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   C:\MHServer\www;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   C:\MHServer\www;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           C:\MHServer\www;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   C:\MHServer\www;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   C:\MHServer\www;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

    #PhpMyAdmin
    server{
        server_name  localhost/phpmyadmin;
    #   access_log  /var/...........................;
        root   C:\MHServer\Phpmyadmin;
        location /phpmyadmin {
                index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Hmmm... could you clarify your comment? In the meanwhile, I didn't see any listen directive inside the server block for phpMyAdmin. Also, consider moving phpMyAdmin to C:\MHServer\www\Phpmyadmin?

Answer (score 1):

My new config with phpMyAdmin
However, when I access phpMyAdmin appears "No input file specified."
PS.: My phpMyAdmin is in inc folder inside the folder NGINX

```
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        include httport;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   /MHServer/www;
            index  index.php index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   /MHServer/www;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        #
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           /MHServer/www;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }

        location /phpmyadmin {
            root inc;
            index  index.php;
        }
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin.+\.php$ {
            root inc;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

            rewrite  ^/phpMyAdmin  /phpmyadmin  last;
            rewrite  ^/pma  /phpmyadmin  last;

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   /MHServer/www;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl                  on;
    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_protocols  SSLv2 SSLv3 TLSv1;
    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers   on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   /MHServer/www;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```

Comment: Thanks. It work for me. I changes the root folder name as html.

Answer (score 0):

```
server {
    listen       80;
    server_name  localhost; 

    location / {
        root   C:\MHServer\www;
        index  index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    location = / {
        root   C:\MHServer\www;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
    }

    #error_page  404              /404.html;

    # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
    #
    error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
    location = /50x.html {
        root   C:\MHServer\www;
    }


    # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
    #
    location ~ \.php$ {
        root           C:\MHServer\www;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
        fastcgi_index  index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
        include        fastcgi_params;
    }

    location /Phpmyadmin {
        root C:\MHServer\;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        location ~ ^/Phpmyadmin/(.+\.php)$ {
            try_files $uri = 404;
            root C:\MHServer\;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }
        location ~* ^/Phpmyadmin/(.+\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|css|png|js|ico|html|xml|txt))$ {
            root C:\MHServer\;
        }
    }

    location /phpmyadmin {
        rewrite ^/* /Phpmyadmin last;
    }

}
```

Comment: did you update the path to phpmyadmin? or try to change the folder name `location /phpMyAdmin {` to `location /Phpmyadmin {`

Comment: By using the NGINX your configuration does not start.

Comment: PS.: I'm using NGINX 1.5.2

Answer (score 0):

```html
#user  nobody;
worker_processes  1;

#error_log  logs/error.log;
#error_log  logs/error.log  notice;
#error_log  logs/error.log  info;

#pid        logs/nginx.pid;


events {
    worker_connections  1024;
}


http {
    include       mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;

    #log_format  main  '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] "$request" '
    #                  '$status $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
    #                  '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';

    #access_log  logs/access.log  main;

    sendfile        on;
    #tcp_nopush     on;

    #keepalive_timeout  0;
    keepalive_timeout  65;

    #gzip  on;

    server {
        listen       8080;
        server_name  localhost;

        #charset koi8-r;

        #access_log  logs/host.access.log  main;

        location / {
            root   html;
            index  index.html index.htm;
        }

        #error_page  404              /404.html;

        # redirect server error pages to the static page /50x.html
        #
        error_page   500 502 503 504  /50x.html;
        location = /50x.html {
            root   html;
        }

        # proxy the PHP scripts to Apache listening on 127.0.0.1:80
        #
        #location ~ \.php$ {
        #    proxy_pass   http://127.0.0.1;
        #}

        # pass the PHP scripts to FastCGI server listening on 127.0.0.1:9000
        
        location ~ \.php$ {
            root           html;
            fastcgi_pass   127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_index  index.php;
            fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME  /scripts$fastcgi_script_name;
            include        fastcgi_params;
        }
  
  location /phpmyadmin {
            root html;
            index  index.php;
        }
            location ~ ^/phpmyadmin.+\.php$ {
            root html;
            fastcgi_index index.php;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
            fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
            include fastcgi_params;
        }

            rewrite  ^/phpMyAdmin  /phpmyadmin  last;
            rewrite  ^/pma  /phpmyadmin  last;

        # deny access to .htaccess files, if Apache's document root
        # concurs with nginx's one
        #
        #location ~ /\.ht {
        #    deny  all;
        #}
    }


    # another virtual host using mix of IP-, name-, and port-based configuration
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       8000;
    #    listen       somename:8080;
    #    server_name  somename  alias  another.alias;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}


    # HTTPS server
    #
    #server {
    #    listen       443 ssl;
    #    server_name  localhost;

    #    ssl_certificate      cert.pem;
    #    ssl_certificate_key  cert.key;

    #    ssl_session_cache    shared:SSL:1m;
    #    ssl_session_timeout  5m;

    #    ssl_ciphers  HIGH:!aNULL:!MD5;
    #    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers  on;

    #    location / {
    #        root   html;
    #        index  index.html index.htm;
    #    }
    #}

}
```